# HTTP GET status code in case of entire collection

Tags: api, http

In case of success of HTTP GET **entire collection** (ex. /users) or **specific item** (Ex. /users/123), we send `200 (OK)`.

In case of (HTTP GET) **specific item**'s ID not found or invalid we send `404 (Not Found)`.

What response should we send in case of (HTTP GET) **entire collection** not found or invalid?

What response should we send in case of (HTTP GET) **entire collection** is empty?

Comment: You can send 404 (Not found) if you want the response to be treated as an error by client. And if you want the response not to be treated as an error you can send 204 (No content). If your case when entire collection is not found or invalid, the code can be 404 (alternatively, use code 500 if you expect the collection to be present and invalid collection is just not desirable). And when the collection is empty, the code can be 204 (404 if you want the response to be treated as an error).

Comment: @NikhilPatil can you please expand on "invalid collection is just not desirable".

Comment: I mean is there a use case where this collection will not exist or is invalid? If not then such scenario will be 'undesirable' meaning your program will not handle it and let the application break. It is important to let the application break when your program is behaving differently than intended.